# ReactJS/Semantic-UI print error on table row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have this part of code from semantic ui in reactjs:

```
<Table.Row className={bu.state.activeIndex === i ? "title Active": "title"}  index={i} onClick={(e) => {bu.Accordion(e, i)}}>
```

Now I want to set [error](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table/#states-error) on this table row:

```
<Table.Row error className={bu.state.activeIndex === i ? "title Active": "title"}  index={i} onClick={(e) => {bu.Accordion(e, i)}}>
```

It work fine, but I want to set error with condition:

```
<Table.Row {value.deleted === 1 ? 'error': null} className={bu.state.activeIndex === i ? "title Active": "title"}  index={i} onClick={(e) => {bu.Accordion(e, i)}}>
```

But it give me error:

> Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected "..." (366:37)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're putting 'error' as a string but it's a parameter of the Table Row. You have to set it to true or false.

```
<Table.Row 
  error={value.deleted === 1 ? true : false } 
  className={bu.state.activeIndex === i ? "title Active": "title"}  
  index={i} 
  onClick={(e) => {bu.Accordion(e, i)}}
>
```